# XSD relation/attribute question

Tags: xml, xsd

I would like to set up an XSD such that it enforces something like a foreign key relationship.  Here's an example:

```
<MappingElement Reference="MySourceElementName"/>

<SourceElement Name="MySourceElementName"/>
```

I would like to specify in the XSD that for any value assigned to the attribute "Reference" must also be a value of a Name attribute in a SourceElement tag.  I know about enumerable restrictions, but the range of values for Name are open ended -- I simply need integrity between my Reference attributes and my Name attributes.  Is there a way to express this with XSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use xs:key and xs:keyref.

[Here's an example](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/XML/Introduction-to-Relations-in-XML-Schema/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the IDREF/IDREFS and ID data types.
the Name attribute would be of type ID and the Reference attribute of type IDREF

Hope that helps!

Comment: ID and IDREF are for use in a DTD, not a schema.

Comment: I agree with the first, but it is used in XML Schema as well as far as me is taught.